# Python ceil function not returning a int, returning floats instead

Tags: python, function, ceil

```
number = 1.23456789
import math
math.ceil(number)
print(number)
```

Expected outcome is `2`, instead the return is the original input of `1.234567`.

I'm learning Python and this is my fourth assignment, the professor even says in their own textbook to simply put `math.ceil(var)` so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: `math.ceil` *returns a new number*, it doesn't (and *can't*) change the original one. Also it rounds *up*, so I don't know why you expected 1. Also it *does* return a float, as documented; `math.ceil(1.234567) == 2.0`.

Comment: ([Reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) can often be productive.)

Comment: why not just `number = int(math.ceil(number))`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that still won't change the original number, note they need to assign it back to something.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I assumed that was understood, but after reading the OP, I guess not?

Comment: "In mathematics and computer science, the floor and ceiling functions map a real number to the largest previous or the smallest following integer, respectively. More precisely, floor(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor  is the largest integer less than or equal to x and ceiling(x) = \lceil x\rceil is the smallest integer greater than or equal to x.[1]"; it sure as hell shouldn't return a float according to that definition.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? Even assigning the return value back to `number`, the type will depend on the Python version.

Comment: when he said float he meant 1.23456789.  I'm sure that he would have been happy with 2.0.  This looks like a math dude's perspective instead of a programmer's perspective.

Comment: @coldspeed because honestly, I didn't know I could do that XD
I thought math.ceil was its own line and couldnt be acted upon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be looking at the return value of math.ceil?

```
number = 1.23456789
import math
number=math.ceil(number)
print(number)
```

Output is

```
$ python blah.py 
2.0
```

So change `number=math.ceil(number)` `number=math.ceil(number)`

Comment: Durp! I hadn't considered being *able* to assign a variable with the math.ceiling in-line. This did it! Thanks man!

Comment: Yeah, most math functions don't modify the argument that you pass into the function; most return the result.  There are exceptions though.  Keep learning Python.  You will love it.